# T-SQL Get all records of a unique key column that contains a column value both not another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hope I can describe it well. I have a table called **TruckAuftragworkflow** where I have a column called **TruckAppId** and a column called **TaskId**. I want to get all **TruckAppId** from that table where the TaskId!=35 but TaskId=31 `OR` TaskId=32.

I tried that and failed:

```
select count(*) AnzahlTasks, TruckAppId from TruckAuftragWorkFlow
GROUP BY TruckAppId
HAVING TaskId != 35 and TaskId in (31,32)
```

Maybe I have a knot in my head but it seems not that easy to build such query (for me!).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count your conditions with an aggregate function

```
select count(*) AnzahlTasks, TruckAppId from TruckAuftragWorkFlow
GROUP BY TruckAppId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN TaskId = 35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN TaskId in (31,32) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Comment: Almost. Add `ELSE 0` in the first expression in order to actually get a zero sum instead of null. Or replace `SUM` by `COUNT`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner True,I was expecting SUM NULL will work,but this is sql server.Thanks.

Comment: Many Thanks. Guys you saved my day. Awesome.